# How to install "Microsoft.Its.Data" package

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm going to install "Microsoft.Its.Data" to my project, but I can't find it. Could somebody guide?
[image]

For example:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that package/project exists?

Comment: It was imported by a real project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to exist. The first interweb search result was the [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/). Maybe the package once existed and was merged or replaced by this one, but that is a wild guess.

If you can compile the project you mentioned in the comments you will most likely have the binaries of this package.

Comment: Thanks, not able to compile the project at this moment. In case I can compile it in the future, may I know how the binaries work for it?

Comment: @Laowantong I don't understand your question. If you can't compile the project because you don't have the required package and you can't obtain this package from somewhere then you are pretty much out of luck I guess.